# invalid KeyPath in immutable js when everything looks fine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I am new to immuatblejs I am pretty confused that I am getting invalid Key path error when my procedure looks fine
[image]

my State

```
const initialState = fromJS({
    text:null,
    master:null,
    inputBoxStatus:false
});
```

master key will filled with array after componentMounted I just want to replace or update the nested array value of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should verify the content of the `master` property just before the `setIn` instruction. If the property `master` contains an `immutable List`, it should work fine, as in this example:

```
const { fromJS } = require('immutable');

const initialState = fromJS({
    text: null,
    master: [{ something: 'fizz' }, { other: 'buzz' }],
    inputBoxStatus: false
});

const modifiedState = initialState.setIn(['master', 0], { test: 'works!' });

console.log(modifiedState.get('master')); // List [ [object Object], Map { "other": "buzz" } ]
```

However, if it contains `null`, it fails with the error message you are showing:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
    text: null,
    master: null,
    inputBoxStatus: false
});

const modifiedState = initialState.setIn(['master', 0], { test: 'works!' });
```

Also note that with this you are introducing the mutable object `{ test: 'works!' }` inside an immutable object. Are you sure that is what you intend?

Comment: ```test:works``` just example I have different values and regarding master state it will filled array values once component Mounted  and this setIn option will trigger when onChange function triggeres so there will be no problem right ?

Comment: As I said,it is difficult to tell without knowing the contents of the `master` property. I suggest that you do a `console.log(yourState.get('master')` just before the line where you do your `setIn` instruction. That way you can see in the console the content of the `master` property.